# hide/unhide jsp element on the basis of other element

Tags: javascript, jsp, show-hide

I want to hide one element when on the basis of other element.

```
<table class="entry" >
    <tr>
        <th><s:text name="security.user.label.authentication-type" /></th>
        <td><s:select 
            name="currentUser.authImpl"
            onchange="DMAINC.module.security.User.removeExpirePassword('%{tabId}');"
            list="@com.dmainc.web.common.security.AuthenticationType@values()"
            headerKey=""
            headerValue="[Please Select]"
            listKey="classname"
            id="authImpl_%{tabId}" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="expireOnLogin" >
        <th><s:text name="security.user.label.expire-password" /></th>
        <td><s:checkbox id="expireOnLog" name="expireOnLogin"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have implemented like below:

```
DMAINC.module.security.User.removeExpirePassword = function(tabId)
{
    var auth = document.getElementById("authImpl_" + tabId).value;
    if(auth=="com.dmainc.commons.security.service.jaas.JAASAuthenticator"){
        var doc = document.getElementById("expireOnLogin");
        doc.style.display = "none";
    }
    else{
        alert(2);
        var doc = document.getElementById("expireOnLogin");
        doc.style.display = "";
    }
};
```

Its working fine but when the authentication type value comes from db it does not hide the checkbox, its working only if I change using select, I want to hide checkbox in both scenario, first if the value is select is coming from db and if i change from UI. I also tried to use if statement to hide but when I change the select it does not find expireOnLogin id.

Answer (score 0):

**Here example is given if you click on Edit content Lore... is disappear and textarea display**

---

```js
<script> 
                function showStuff(id, text, btn) {
                    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
                    // hide the lorem ipsum text
                    document.getElementById(text).style.display = 'none';
                    // hide the link
                    btn.style.display = 'none';
                }
            </script>
```

```html
            <td class="post">

                <a href="#" onclick="showStuff('answer1', 'text1', this);
        return false;">Edit</a>
                <span id="answer1" style="display: none;">
                    <textarea rows="10" cols="115"></textarea>
                </span>

                <span id="text1">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</span>
          </td>
```